# Crear un selectinput dependiente en Dtedit

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Tengo un dataframe con la lista de regiones y países. Sin embargo, necesito que cuando selecciones una región, por ejemplo América, en la siguiente entrada de selección solo puedas seleccionar los países correspondientes.

**Nota:** Hay que instalar la version 2.3.0 DTedit

```
devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.3.0')
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(DTedit)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output) {
  book <- data.frame(Region = c("Americas","Americas","Americas","Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific","EMEA","EMEA","Africa","Africa"),
                     Country = c("","USA","Colombia","China","India","Germany","Spain","South Africa","Cameroon"),
                     Rating = c(2,5,3,5,4,5,4,3,1))
  
  Country_List_Results <- dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'Country_List',
    thedata = book,
    edit.cols = c('Region', 'Country', 'Rating'),
    edit.label.cols = c('Region', 'Country', 'Rating'),
    input.types = c(Region = 'selectInput', Country = 'selectInput'),
    input.choices = list(Country = mylist()),
    view.cols = names(book)
  )
  
  output$selectedrow <- shiny::eventReactive(Country_List_Results$rows_selected,
                                             ignoreInit = TRUE, {paste0("selected ID: ", Country_List_Results$rows_selected)})
  
  fila <- reactive({ Country_List_Results$rows_selected })
  output$Region <- renderText({ Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] })
  observeEvent(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()], { message(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] )})
  
  mylist <- reactive({
    if(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] == "Americas"){c("Bolivia","USA","Colombia")
    } else if(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] == "Asia Pacific") {c("China","India")
    } else if(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] == "EMEA") {c("Germany","Spain")
    } else if(Country_List_Results$thedata$Region[fila()] == "Africa") {c("South Africa","Cameroon")
    } else {""}
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('Country List'),
  uiOutput('Country_List'),
  verbatimTextOutput('selectedrow'),
  verbatimTextOutput('fila'),
  verbatimTextOutput('Region')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

He realizado una actualización donde, me aproximo mas al problema a resolver. Sin embargo ocurre un problema, cuando le doy editar a un registro de *Americas*, me salen los correspondientes países hasta ahí funciona, sin embargo cuando selecciono otra Region como *Africa*, me salen solo los países de America.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo único que naturalmente podrías hacer con `dtedit` es configurar cada combo para que muestre las opciones adecuadas, lo cual lo lograrías con el parámetro `input.choices`, y por cierto las cadenas en el df tienen que ser factores sino no funciona. Lo que buscas, que sin duda es una inquietud razonable, no hay forma de resolverlo con `dtedit` a menos que entres a modificar el código de la función. Esperemos que alguien lo haya resuelto por que es un funcionalidad muy útil

Comment: Hola Patricio gracias por el consejo he realizado una actualización del código, estoy un poco más cerca pero sigo sin resolverlo.

Comment: No conocía ese fork o branch de `dtedit`, así que gracias por el dato, igualmente lo que has logrado también se podía conseguir con la versión anterior. Lo que me parece es que no se puede dar lógica interactiva al modal que se abre, es decir, que cuando seleccionas un combo se actualice el otro, he visto la documentación y los ejemplos y no hay ningún caso similar.  Pero, es una apreciación en la que no estoy 100% seguro, habría que investigar un poco más.